# Show state of matter with chemmacros

Tags: chemmacros

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{CaCO3 <=> Ca^{2+}{\aq} + CO3^{2-}{\aq}}

\end{document}
```

How do I show that the calcium carbonate is in a solid state? I tried both

```
CaCO3{\s}
```

and

```
CaCO3{\solid}
```

but neither `\s` nor `\solid` are defined. (The manual can be found [here](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf).)

Comment: It's `\sld`, see section 19 _Phases_ of the manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 19 of the manual, *Phases*, lists all predefined phase macros:

- `\sld` (s)
- `\lqd` (l)
- `\gas` (g)
- `\aq` (aq)

There's also the `\phase{<phase>}` command and it is possible to define additional phase commands which will obey `chemmacros`' `phase` options.

```
\ch{CaCO3\sld}
```

[image]

Comment: Why in chemmacros manual it is written as \sld{} and not as \sld? What is the difference?

Comment: @Anton after `\foo ` is no space, it only determines the end of the macro, after `\foo{} ` _is_ a space. Within the argument of `chemformula`'s `\ch` spaces often are important, so that's why.